# How can I calculate RPM for a DIY custom BLDC motor that works on 12/24 volts?

Tags: voltage, brushless-dc-motor, winding, rpm

I'm working on a project where I'm designing a 12/24V BLDC motor. I have nine slots for winding and eight neodymium magnets. I used [this](https://www.bavaria-direct.co.za/scheme/calculator/) for calculating the winding factor which is 0.94521 and winding rolls in slots will be 72 rounds per slot. I'm designing an inrunner motor for higher RPM.

How can I get an approximate RPM value with this information?

Comment: If it's brushless, the RPM is defined by how quickly you switch your coils. So what feedback method are you using (Hall sensor or back emf or something else)? What switching technology (IGBTs or FETs or something else) are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! I'm using Hall sensor circuit for feedback and FET based speed controller.

Comment: It will spin as fast as you control it to spin until you set your coils on fire or it mechanically breaks down.

Comment: What are you using to calculate switching (MCU or FPGA or something else) What is the update rate of your hall sensor? We need a datasheet of your FETs too. What are you driving your FETs with? With the information we have at the moment, there is no limit to your RPM.

Comment: At the moment, I have decided to use FET based speed controller. I'm using [link](https://ibb.co/SwbMGC1) this circuit for speed control and [link](https://ibb.co/CnFGkf1) hall sensor circuit. I got both of them online.

Comment: We need links to the datasheets. What is doing the processing from the Hall sensor to control the FETs? Update your question with links to all the datasheets.